# Using Haversine formula filtering with Mysql and PHP for a search value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP script that filters a received value ($r) with location data associated with  using the haversine formula to only show values that are within a certain distance of the point received. The below script is failing for some reason and I cannot tell if it is functionally incorrect or if its as something as simple as a syntax error (scanned through character by character multiple times and can't see anything wrong, but I could be wrong)

The value received is in this form:
[search_value]latlong[lat_value]latlong[long_value]

Example:

Item1latlong26.2616236latlong25.6010943

The PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php

include('db.php');

$r = strval($_GET['r']);

$parts = explode('latlong', $r);

$term = $parts[0];
$latitude = $parts[1];
$longitude = $parts[2];

$distance = 1;

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"db");
$search="SELECT *, (((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin(('lat'*pi()/180)) + cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos(('lat'*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- 'lng')*pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distance FROM 'table_data' WHERE distance <= ".$distance." AND type = '".$term."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$search);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "var map;";
echo "var markers = [];";
echo "var locations = [";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "[" . $row['merchant'] . ".info," . $row['merchant'] . ".lat," . $row['merchant'] . ".lng," . $row['merchant'] . ".type," . $row['merchant'] . ".label," . $row['userid'] . "],";
};

echo "];";

echo "</script>";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

In the above 'lat' and 'long' correspond to the appropriate columns in the appropriate table where a list of items is stored, each with their own location data.

Any recommendations on improvements are welcome (I am new to php) and help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You cannot use the distance alias with WHERE. Either change to HAVING or re-state the formula.

Comment: And note that your code is open to injection

Comment: @Strawberry thanks! So essentially replacing "WHERE" with "HAVING" would resolve? Still planning on including php filters - I assume that that would clear injection risk?

Comment: Injection only requires the use of prepared and bound queries

Comment: There are other problems here. But it's a bit tedious to iterate through them

Comment: Hmmm - thanks again for pointing out and I'll take that into consideration. Injection aside, the statement itself - I've tried this out with "HAVING" and this did not solve?

Comment: @Strawberry I've tried this out and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I know. While in 'development', you have to develop some system of basic error reporting

Answer (score 0):

If it's useful, here's a stored function for calculating distances on Earth in km...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION geo_distance_km(lat1 double, lon1 double, lat2 double, lon2 double) RETURNS double
begin
   declare R int DEFAULT 6372.8;
   declare phi1 double;
   declare phi2 double;
   declare d_phi double;
   declare d_lambda double;
   declare a double;
   declare c double;
   declare d double;
   set phi1 = radians(lat1);
   set phi2 = radians(lat2);
   set d_phi = radians(lat2-lat1);
   set d_lambda = radians(lon2-lon1);
   set a = sin(d_phi/2) * sin(d_phi/2) +
         cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) *
         sin(d_lambda/2) * sin(d_lambda/2);
   set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
   set d = R * c;
   return d;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Example of usage:

```
<?php

/*
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,userid INT NOT NULL
,merchant INT NOT NULL
,latitude DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL
,longitude DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL
,type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1, 100, 1000, 30.45180,31.236083,'Item1'),
(2, 101, 1000, 26.26162,25.601094,'Item1'),
(3, 101, 1001, 30.36100,31.232080,'Item1'),
(4, 102, 1002, 30.45180,31.236083,'Item1'),
(5, 103, 1003, 30.44473,31.241958,'Item1'),
(6, 103, 1003, 26.26150,25.601000,'Item2'),
(7, 103, 1004, 30.45180,31.236083,'Item2');
*/

require('path/to/pdo/connection/stateme.nts');

$r = 'Item1latlong26.2616236latlong25.6010943';

$parts = explode('latlong', $r);

$term = $parts[0];
$latitude = $parts[1];
$longitude = $parts[2];

$distance = 1;

$query="
SELECT merchant
     , userid
     , geo_distance_km(:latitude,:longitude,latitude,longitude) distance
  FROM my_table
 WHERE type = :term
HAVING distance < :distance
   ";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':latitude', $latitude, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':longitude', $longitude, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':distance', $distance, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':term', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch();

print_r($result);


?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [merchant] => 1000 [userid] => 101 [distance] => 0.0004015440080907 )
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is only another approach to the haversine function in PHP

Comment: @Nick1991 FWIW, I think this is a recommendation on an improvement - the kind of thing you indicated would be welcome and appreciated. My mistake, I guess.

Comment: @Nick1991 Anyway, I've added an example of usage.

Comment: thanks! I missed this and only picked up now and I like the method - As I mentioned, I'm quite new to PHP - I want to try and replicate your example to learn from - I created your my_table example as a table as well as adding the exact stored routine you suggest for the db in phpmyadmin, however when I try and run your suggested php script I get a 500 error? Not sure if something is wrong there as I can't see it, but would really like to learn from this (I will answer the q with the end result once this is working for future SO use)